# C# CSV File : How to skip few columns while reading csv file using datatable

Tags: c#, csv, datatable

There are some conditional columns which i need to skip while reading csv  using datatable.
For example:  My csv file has headers like `Emp_Id, Emp_Name,Dept , Role , Addree and Salary`. I want to skip `Emp_Name` and `Role` column while reading csv file and import the rest.

Emp_id **Emp_Name**    Dept    **Role**    Address Salary

I am using below code to read csv file without any column skip But now i want to skip some columns: 
List listOfCol = new List();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

```
        for (int i = 1; i <= colCount; i++)
        {
            string colName = XlRange.Cells[1, i].Value2.ToString();
            DataColumn dataColumn = new DataColumn(colName);
            dt.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
            listOfCol.Add(colName);
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            DataRow dataRow = dt.NewRow();

            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                if (XlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && XlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                {
                    dataRow[listOfCol[j - 1].ToString()] = XlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    dataRow[listOfCol[j - 1].ToString()] = "";
                }
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }
```

Comment: How are you reading the file currently?  By "skip" you mean you want to avoid loading those columns/fields into the `DataTable` as opposed to removing those columns after loading all the data?

Comment: Currently i am reading all headers (column)without any filteration. Yes, i want to avoid loading those columns into datatable.

Comment: Yes, but _how_ are you doing that?  Are you parsing the file yourself, or using a library?  It'd be helpful if you provided your code so answers could show you how to modify or improve it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you are already building DataTable.

You may try NuGet package csvHelper

And a class definition that looks like this.

```
public class Foo {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

If our class property names match our CSV file header names, we can read the file without any configuration.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader("path\\to\\file.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)) {
    var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
}
```

To select only specific columns use column index

```
public class Foo { 
    [Index(0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
 }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you put the sample code you are working with so we can assist better. The crude way to do it would be as your read each line of the csv file spilt it by the delimiter which returns an array of your items and you cherry pick by index to add to you datatable.